# use Pod instead of import Parse and Bolts framework

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

Currently I have a project and import Parse and Bolts framework manually.
I want to use Pod to instead of manually import. After Pod install, Build project is fine.
However, When I use simulator to run project then get below error message

> fatal error: lipo: input file (/Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified
>   fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts-x86_64 (No such file or directory)
>   mv: /Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts-merged: No such file or directory
>   rm: /Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts-x86_64: No such file or directory
>
> fatal error: lipo: input file (/Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified
>   fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse-x86_64 (No such file or directory)
>   mv: /Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse-merged: No such file or directory
>   rm: /Users/anchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse-x86_64: No such file or directory

use simulator run app will display error message, after clear and re-run will success. However, stop simulator and re-run will fail. That means, every time run simulator I have to clear first. Have any expert can help ? (xcode 7.3.1)

Comment: Delete Framework from Applocation and install using POD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348912/lipo-error-cant-open-input-file

Comment: i had viewed the topic that you mention above, but, not work for me

Comment: try to delete Derived data (in xcode->Window->Projects->delete derived data)

Comment: had deleted Derived data, but still not work