# Lipo: input file must be a fat file

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

I'm getting following error:

> Extracting arm64 from Alamofire fatal error: lipo: input file
>   (../myApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire) must be a fat
>   file when the -extract option is specified

always when I want to run the app. It doesn't show up when I clean before, but it takes super long time.

This => [Lipo Error!! can't open input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348912/lipo-error-cant-open-input-file) is not my case and it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas,

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In target -> Build Phases -> Run script I had some incompatible script.

I removed it and the app works now!