# Xcode 9.4 fatal error: lipo: can't open input file (No such file or directory)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, frameworks

I have developed a framework which was working fine till Xcode 9 but recently I updated my Xcode to version 9.4 and now when I Archive/Run the the project, it generates the .framework file but gives an error.

**Error is attached here**

[image]

> fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/swift-developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShuftiPro-erwkmqdpkoprcngduyssdgzuhqfw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/UniversalShuftiPro/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/ShuftiPro.framework/ShuftiPro (No such file or directory)
>
> Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Here are the framework [build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86mBe.png) attached.

And when I import that compiled framework into other projects, it says:

> "Cannot load underlying module for 'ShuftiPro'"

I have given a lot of time to solve this and followed a number of solutions here but got no success.

[image]

Comment: have u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348912/lipo-error-cant-open-input-file?rq=1

Comment: Yes but that didn't work also

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673866/cocoapods-cannot-load-underlying-module-for-x

Comment: guru i am not using pods

Comment: Have you try to clear DerivedData?

Comment: Yes i did this as well but no success

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that either the file or not. It seems like the file doesn't exits or there is permission error.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `Build Active Architecture` Only to `YES` in Build Setting tab, then it will work